# I installed MAUI on VS but I can't find NuGet packages in the MAUI project

Tags: visual-studio, maui, visual-studio-installer

I installed MAUI with Visual Studio Installer (I ticked the ".NET Multi-plateform App UI development").

Then when i create a MAUI project it creates well but all the references of MAUI are missing.
The error is `Error CS0234 Type or namespace name 'Maui' does not exist in the 'Microsoft' namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)`.

Indeed when I check the installed NuGet packages, they are not here (like if they are not installed).

How can I install MAUI NuGets packages to have them in my project?

Comment: "maui-check" might help you to make sure your MAUI install is correct. More here https://github.com/Redth/dotnet-maui-check

Else I would close the solution, delete bin/obj.. open the solution, restore packages, and then would try to build..

Comment: MAUI is not deployed as a nuget package

Comment: @Jason Ok but i do not have access to the namespace : "Microsoft.Maui"

Comment: @NSubedi thanks for your help but it's not the csproj that not has MAUI it's all my MAUI projects... How can i restore global packages?

Comment: You can check whether the SDK for Maui is installed during installation. Have you tried reinstalling VS to see if the problem still occurs? You can open VS and click the avatar in the upper right corner -> Report a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have already had the same problem. The cause of the problem was that Visual Studio Installer was installing the files in `C:\Program Files` while Visual Studio was trying to find the SDKs in `C:\Program Files (x86)`. I had this behaviour because in my Path (environment variable) I had the paths `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet` AND `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet`.

If this is the case for you, delete `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet` from your Path, reboot your PC, and restart Visual Studio. It should take the correct configuration.

Comment: "delete C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet from your Path"

how? It isn't in my path variable.

Comment: I tried the opposite and added it to my path variable. This actually got nuget to work for 1 single install and after that it broke again.